# Why can't we use unique identifier as combination of email and password?

Tags: authentication, login

For prevent email conflicts for authentication system we can surely choose email and password combination as unique identifier.

What can prevent me to built authentication system by treating unique identifier as  combination of email and password ? What is wrong with this design ?

Comment: You want to have multiple users with the same email address? Why? If you aren't going to use the address for sending email to it, why not use a nice real user name instead?

Comment: You would want to store the password in plain text? Anyway you can't be sure that an email is unique you can't also be sure that a password is. The whole thing sounds weird. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: and how do you identify the user for the "lost password" feature? :-)

Comment: @thorstenmüller we can use primary id of user as unique and at login step we can look at user who has same email and password. I haven't understand that why it is related to hold password in plain text ?

Comment: Even if you hash the password, there's a huge security flaw: A user (`user@domain.com`) changes his password from `password` to `letmein`. Another user with email `user@domain.com` is already using `letmein` as his password. `Error: This email/password combination already exists`. Oh hey, now this user can access someone else's account!

Comment: @Freshblood seems I misunderstood your intention. When you write "unique identifier as combination of email and password" it sounds a bit like you want to do something like storing "xyz@xxx.com_thepassword" as unique identifier in your db. Seems you just mean that somebody can login using his email + password. As long as your users can't create multiple accounts with the same email that would be ok (many sites do this actually, not least of them gmail). (Others seem to understand it that way too, maybe make clearer what you want to do)

Comment: @Kai we can use primary id number in such cases.

Answer (score 7):

The immediate issue here is that a user's password can, and *should* change occasionally. By tying your unique ID to the password, you're effectively creating a new user account whenever a user changes his password.

If possible, the unique identifier should be something that *never* changes. If you have some sort of set-in-stone ID such as an employee ID or Social Security/ID Number, use that. If you don't, you should create a unique identifier in your database and use that as a reference. Passwords, as well as email addresses and names, might change.

A second problem here, as noted in the comments, is that a user's password should *never* be stored in plain text. You should be hashing the password and storing only that hash. Better yet, whatever security framework you use should be doing it for you.

Comment: Social Security numbers are supposed to be unique, but they are not - turns out that the government makes some errors, and not everyone has one, and to fix errors, some people's social changes.  Some people have dual citizenship with more than one social.  Integer data types can pack more information per byte than any other.  Surrogate keys FTW!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Comment: SSN's will run out of numbers in 100 years. While it may seem ridiculous to think a program we write now would last 100 years, the Y2K bug happened because no one thought the program would still be around when it would happen. Who even knows if SSN's will be used for another 20 years (A fairly realistic time-line for many console programs), I know that I'm NOT counting on SS for retirement...